# Update json object with key and condition with db trigger

Tags: json, postgresql, triggers

I've got the following tables:

```sql
create table margins (
  id serial primary key,
  margins JSON,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  institution_uuid UUID NOT NULL,
  created_by VARCHAR
);
```

and

```sql
create table margin_defaults (
  id serial primary key,
  model VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  margin FLOAT NOT NULL,
  created_by VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

I store the following array of object in the column `margins` or the table `margins`

```sql
insert into margins (margins, created_at, institution_uuid, created_by) VALUES ('[{"model": "samsungS23","margin": "0.5","type": "CUSTOM"},{"model": "iphone",,"margin": "0.2","type": "CUSTOM"},{"model": "pixel","margin": "0.2","type": "CUSTOM"}]', '2023-12-12 15:38:40.642428', '51d8060e-5a31-4575-b56d-c5100e94d614', 'test-runner') RETURNING *;
```

In the `margin_defaults` table I store all the default values for the different types of margins.This table is an append/create table, so no row are ever updated. The same for the `margins` table. However when a new entry is added to the `margin_defaults` table, I want to be able to get the last set of entries for each `institution_uuid` in the margins table and update the corresponding object in the `margins` column with the same `type` as the that of the new `margin_defauts` entry but only when the current margin `type` is set to `DEFAULT`.

I've come up with the following trigger so far, but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], double precision) does not exist
LINE 3:      jsonb_set(r.margins::jsonb, ('{' || tmp_position || ',m...
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO margins (institution_uuid, margins, created_by) VALUES (
                    r.institution_uuid,
                    jsonb_set(r.margins::jsonb, ('{' || tmp_position || ',margin}')::text[], NEW.margin)::json,
                    NEW.created_by
                )
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_margins_default_values_function() line 10 at SQL statement
```

My trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_margins_default_values_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
DECLARE tmp_position int;
BEGIN
        FOR r IN
                SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.institution_uuid) * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (institution_uuid) * FROM margins ORDER BY institution_uuid, created_at DESC) as b WHERE b.margins::jsonb@>'[{"type":"DEFAULT"}]' ORDER BY institution_uuid
        LOOP
            SELECT position FROM jsonb_array_elements(r.margins::jsonb) with ordinality arr(elem, position) INTO tmp_position WHERE elem->>'model'=NEW.model AND elem->>'type'='DEFAULT';
            IF found THEN
                INSERT INTO margins (institution_uuid, margins, created_by) VALUES (
                    r.institution_uuid,
                    jsonb_set(r.margins::jsonb, ('{' || tmp_position || ',margin}')::text[], NEW.margin)::json,
                    NEW.created_by
                );
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_margins_default_values_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON margin_defaults FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_margins_default_values_function();
```

A fiddle that I'm trying to get work - [sqlFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AyLmENLX)

Comment: As the error is telling you `r`(record) is not a relation. See [Record](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) for what it is.

Comment: I've updated the function and the error has now changed

Comment: Read the docs here [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-json.html) for what is required as `jsonb_set()` arguments.

Comment: Here's the fiddle after fixing a few layers of errors, reactively, without reading into what you're actually attempting to do: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/icE_P20k). If all those layers of *wrong* are there because you're using generative AI to spawn it, [please don't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy). Another guess as to how you got this many layers of errors all at once is that you might've attempted to write it all in one go, without checking with the doc or testing in small steps. In either case, the development process needs way more improvement than its result.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the helpful comments to my question I found the solution.

`SELECT position FROM jsonb_array_elements(r.margins) with ordinality arr(elem, position) INTO tmp_position` return the first value with index starting at `1` and not `0`, so need to subtract `1` from this value when inserting back into the array.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_margins_default_values_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
DECLARE tmp_position int;
BEGIN
        FOR r IN
                SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.institution_uuid) *
                FROM (
                        SELECT DISTINCT ON (institution_uuid) * FROM margins ORDER BY institution_uuid, created_at DESC
                ) as b WHERE b.margins::jsonb@>'[{"type":"DEFAULT"}]' ORDER BY institution_uuid
        LOOP
                SELECT position
                FROM jsonb_array_elements(r.margins::jsonb) with ordinality arr(elem, position)
                INTO tmp_position
                WHERE elem->>'model'=NEW.model AND elem->>'type'='DEFAULT';
                IF found THEN
                        INSERT INTO margins (institution_uuid, margins, created_by) VALUES (
                                r.institution_uuid,
                                jsonb_set(r.margins::jsonb, ('{' || tmp_position - 1 || ',margin}')::text[], to_jsonb(NEW.margin))::json,
                                NEW.created_by
                        );
                END IF;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_margins_default_values_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON margin_defaults FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_margins_default_values_function();
```